# Remove RTE Title Text in TYPO3 6.1

Tags: typo3, rte, typo3-6.1.x, tsconfig

RTE still clutters any link with `title="Opens external link in new window"` and worse, `title="Opens internal link in current window"`.

I've tried removing it with

```
RTE.classesAnchor.externalLinkInNewWindow.titleText >
RTE.classesAnchor.internalLinkInCurrentWindow.titleText >
```

in page TSconfig, but no luck. Actually, I'm not even sure if this has to go into TSConfig or TS.

How can I disable this legacy feature?

PS I *do* still use

```
config.extTarget = _blank
```

but if it's really necessary, I can turn it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove all `title` attributes from links when saving:

```
RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db.tags.a.fixAttrib.title.unset = 1
```

Comment: Sounds good - do I have to re-save all articles (or search-replace)? Or is there a way to strip it from the rendered output too?

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of these texts, right of the beginning of a project (before content is filled in) use this PageTS-Config:

```
## get rid of "Opens link in ..."
RTE.classesAnchor.externalLink.titleText >
RTE.classesAnchor.externalLinkInNewWindow.titleText >
RTE.classesAnchor.internalLink.titleText >
RTE.classesAnchor.internalLinkInNewWindow.titleText >
RTE.classesAnchor.download.titleText >
RTE.classesAnchor.mail.titleText >
```

To look for the right names, go into the Module "Info", select a page from the page tree, click "Page TS Config" on the Dropdown-Select on the Top, and then "RTE." on the following Dropdown-Select.